# Remove elements at certain positions from all sub-lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a big list where all the inner lists' lengths are the same

```
 list = {{x1, y1, z1, t1}, {x2, y2, z2, t2}, {x3, y3, z3, t3}, ...};
 elementNo = {4, 3, 2};
```

I want output like this,

```
{{x1}, {x2}, {x3}, ...}
```

That is, when I specify `elementNo` as `{4, 3, 2}`, I mean the elements at positions 2, 3 and 4 in the sub-lists should be removed -- I want the elements at position 1 only. When I specify `elementNo` as `{2, 3}`, I want

```
 {{x1, t1}, {x2, t2}, {x3, t3}, ...}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hm... okay, I guess I see now.  You should describe this problem as deleting elements, as that is what it is.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I tried for getting that output,but I didn't get it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard we have to remove the specific position elements from the main list,that specific element position getting from `elementNO`.

Comment: I answered this.  Please take the time to Accept some of the answers to your earlier questions.

Comment: @m_goldberg You're obsessive about your edits, aren't you?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Yes, I suppose I am, but don't you think my edit made the question clearer? Are you suggesting I hold back?

Answer (score 10):

Another option:

```
f[list_, pos_] := Module[{x = list},
  x[[All, pos]] = Sequence[];
  x]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
f1[list_, spec_] := With[{sp = List /@ spec}, Delete[#, sp] & /@ list]

f1[list, {4, 3, 2}]
f1[list, {2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{x1}, {x2}, {x3}}
> {{x1, t1}, {x2, t2}, {x3, t3}}
> ```

```
f2[list_, spec_] := list[[ All, Complement[Range@Length@First@list, spec] ]]

f2[list, {4, 3, 2}]
f2[list, {2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{x1}, {x2}, {x3}}
> {{x1, t1}, {x2, t2}, {x3, t3}}
> ```

Comment: +1. Note that a more efficient form of `List /@ spec`is `Transpose[{spec}]`.

Comment: @Leonid True, however I thought clarity might be better for this answer, and `f2` is the higher performance method anyway.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
list = RandomInteger[50, {10, 4}]
new = {};
elemNo = {4, 3, 2};
new = Map[Delete[#, {{elemNo[[1]]}, {elemNo[[2]]}, {elemNo[[3]]}}] &,list]
```

Comment: That won't work if the `elemNo` list is a different length.  It's also not efficiently written, as you could much more easily do:  `Map[Delete[#, List /@ elemNo] &, list]`.  This is what I did in my answer for the function `f1` but with the additional optimization of doing the `List /@ elemNo` *once* and inserting it using `With`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative:

```
f[list_, pos_] := With[{p = pos ~Sort~ Greater}, Fold[# ~Drop~ {#2} &, #, p] & /@ list]

f[list, {2, 3}]
(* {{x1, t1}, {x2, t2}, {x3, t3}} *)
```

If you can guarantee that the positions to be dropped will be input in descending order, you can drop the sorting step.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{x1, y1, z1, t1}, {x2, y2, z2, t2}, {x3, y3, z3, t3}};
elementNo = {4, 3, 2};

MapAt[Nothing, list, Thread[{All, elementNo}]]
```

> {{x1}, {x2}, {x3}}

Answer (score 1):

here is the way I would do it using my Excel mindset,

```
list = {{x1, y1, z1, t1}, {x2, y2, z2, t2}, {x3, y3, z3, t3}};
elementNo = {4, 3, 2};
todelete = {#} & /@ Sort@elementNo
tokeep = Delete[Range@Length@First@list, todelete]
remaining = Take[list, All, tokeep]
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using `Outer` and `Extract`:

```
data = {{x1, y1, z1, t1}, {x2, y2, z2, t2}, {x3, y3, z3, t3}};
unwanted1 = {4, 3, 2};
unwanted2 = {2, 3};

extractComplement[data_List, spec_List] :=
  Module[{dataSize, subSize, survivors},
    dataSize = Length@data;
    subSize = Length@data[[1]];
    survivors = Outer[List, Range@dataSize, Complement[Range@subSize, spec]];
    Extract[data, #] & /@ survivors]

extractComplement[data, unwanted1]
```

> {{x1}, {x2}, {x3}}

```
extractComplement[data, unwanted2]
```

> {x1, t1}, {x2, t2}, {x3, t3}

Answer (score 1):

If all sublists are indeed of the same length, use `Transpose`:

```
Transpose@Delete[Transpose@list, List /@ elementNo]
```

> ```
> {{x1}, {x2}, {x3}}
> ```

Note that you can use the shorthand notation for `Transpose`, which makes the code **really short**:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With other `elementNo`:

```
elementNo = {3, 2};
Transpose@Delete[Transpose@list, List /@ elementNo]
```

> ```
> {{x1, t1}, {x2, t2}, {x3, t3}}
> ```

Comment: While you're using `Transpose` how about `Delete[list\[Transpose], {elementNo}\[Transpose]]\[Transpose]`?  Looks great in the Notebook. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've set my `PerformanceGoal` to `"Speed"` instead of `"CodeGolf"`. An extra `Transpose` might be just too much for a modern computer... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{x1, y1, z1, t1}, {x2, y2, z2, t2}, {x3, y3, z3, t3}};

ps = {4, 3, 2};
```

Since Version 13.1 there is `ReplaceAt`:

```
ReplaceAt[list, _ -> Nothing, Thread[{All, ps}]]
```

{{x1}, {x2}, {x3}}

```
ReplacePart[list, {_, Alternatives @@ ps} -> Nothing]
```

{{x1}, {x2}, {x3}}

Answer (score 0):

Using `ArrayRules` and `Select`:

```
list = {{x1, y1, z1, t1}, {x2, y2, z2, t2}, {x3, y3, z3, t3}};
ps = {4, 3, 2};

Values@Select[Rule[Last@#[[1]], {#[[2]]}] & /@ Most@ArrayRules[list], 
FreeQ[#[[1]], Alternatives @@ ps] &]

(*{{x1}, {x2}, {x3}}*)
```

Or using `Table`:

```
Table[If[Or @@ Thread[j == ps], Nothing, list[[i, j]]], {i, #}, {j, #}] &@Length@list

(*{{x1}, {x2}, {x3}}*)
```